# Why does the king blame Elisha for the siege and famine of Samaria in 2 Kings 6:31?

Tags: prophecy, 2-kings, elisha

2 Kings 6:31

> 31 He said, “May God deal with me, be it ever so severely, if the head of Elisha son of Shaphat remains on his shoulders today!”

After undergoing a siege which culminated in a severe famine the king of Israel seems to blame all this on Elisha the prophet

Why does the king blame Elisha for his misfortunes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a generational hatred. Before Joram became king, there was another famine and another prophet in 1 Kings 18

> 1 After a long time, in the third year, the word of the Lord came to **Elijah**: “Go and present yourself to Ahab, and I will send rain on the land.” 2So Elijah went to present himself to Ahab.
>
> Now the **famine** was severe in Samaria, 3and Ahab had summoned Obadiah, his palace administrator. (Obadiah was a devout believer in the Lord. 4While **Jezebel was killing off the Lord’s prophets**, Obadiah had taken a hundred prophets and hidden them in two caves, fifty in each, and had supplied them with food and water.)

Joram inherited the kingship after Ahab.
Elisha inherited the prophetship after Elijah.

Joram was the son of Ahab and Jezebel. He inherited the hatred as well as the kingdom. For this OP, one key is Jezebel.

1 Kings 19

> 1 Now Ahab told **Jezebel** everything Elijah had done and how he had killed all the [**her**] prophets with the sword. 2So Jezebel sent a messenger to Elijah to say, “May the gods deal with me, be it ever so severely, if by this time tomorrow I do not make your life like that of one of them.”

Jezebel was a strong character and wanted revenge by killing Elijah but she failed. She indoctrinated her son Joram as she indoctrinated her husband Ahab.

> 1 Kings 16:30 Ahab son of Omri did more evil in the eyes of the Lord than any of those before him. 31He not only considered it trivial to commit the sins of Jeroboam son of Nebat, but he also married **Jezebel** daughter of Ethbaal king of the Sidonians, and began to **serve Baal and worship him**.

> 1 Kings 21:7 Jezebel his wife said, "Is this how you act as king over Israel? Get up and eat! Cheer up. I'll get you the vineyard of Naboth the Jezreelite."

So, Joram found it expedient to blame Elisha for the siege and famine because of his mother Jezebel's influence.

There is a strong parallel between Ahab-Elijah and Joram-Elisha including lastly the endings of the famines.

> 1 Kings 18:41 And Elijah said to Ahab, "Go, eat and drink, for there is the sound of a heavy rain."

> 2 Kings 7:1 Elisha replied, "Hear the word of the LORD. This is what the LORD says: About this time tomorrow, a seah of the finest flour will sell for a shekel and two seahs of barley for a shekel at the gate of Samaria."

The famines ended with both Ahab and Joram enjoying eating and drinking upon the words of Elijah and Elisha.

There are no reasons for these kings to hate these prophets except by the influence of Jezebel.

Answer (score 1):

The King was wicked and didn't want to repent and follow God with his whole heart.He kept blaming the prophet since he was an easier target.The famine wouldn't have happened if he had obeyed God(we are all called to be obedient to God and His Messiah).

"Joram son of Ahab became king of Israel in Samaria in the eighteenth year of Jehoshaphat king of Judah, and he reigned twelve years.He did evil in the eyes of the Lord" 2 King 3

"While Elisha was still speaking with them, the messenger came down to him. And the king said, “This calamity is from the LORD. Why should I wait for the LORD any longer?” 2 king 6:33

Now Elisha had said to the woman whose son he had restored to life, “Go away with your family and stay for a while wherever you can, because the Lord has decreed a famine in the land that will last seven years. 2 King 8